# iOS11 setting the Launch Screen File messes the UI

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios11, xcode9

I have an old iOS App built with old Xcode and configurations, such that the "Launch Screen File" in Xcode wasn't set, and the App Icon was set in the plist.
When updating to Xcode 9 and iOS 11, I set the App Icons using Asset Catalog.
After running the app on iPhone X, I noticed that it runs in Compatibility Mode.

Then, I have set the Launch Screen File to the new xib file I have created, and then it launched without compatibility mode. But what happened is that the font got smaller, and some constraints got misplaced. Check the Screenshot below.

Any idea?

[image: Screen shot]

Configurations:

[image: Xcode Config]

**Edit:**
I have Safe Area Layout Guide Enabled.

Comment: If you've constraints, it is recommended to enable `Use safe Area Layout Guides`, used for iPhone X layout, by going to *Storyboard->show file inspector->Use safe Area Layout Guides.*

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I already have the Safe Area Layout Guides Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into the same issue. I'm sensing that there's no easy fix to this problem. Something having to do with the launch images messes with the window in some way. The annoying part is that Apple forces you to change these images in order to be submitted to the App Store.

It looks like compatibility mode works by 'zooming in'. This can also be confirmed by looking at the keyboard differences. You'll now get the 'modern' keyboard (smaller keys) instead of the zoomed in version. I have not found a solution to this problem other than manually fixing the differences.